# Formatting Decimal Number in SQL

Tags: sql-server

How would I get rid of a decimal point in SQL? I do not want to round the number.

for example....

Input: 12.67

Desired output: 1267

Thank you!

Comment: What have you researched? What have you tried? There are loads of questions which already answer this, and SQL Server has a bunch of helpful functions which will help you accomplish this. Or simple math will convert 2dp to 0dp.

Comment: Based on your question history I would highly advise you to put some time into writing better questions because you are likely to hit a question ban at this rate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace('12.67','.','')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is numeric then multiply by 100

```
select round(input*100, 0);
```

Comment: This assumes there's always exactly two decimal places.